# change section name in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sections

When I write a simple program in Visual Studio with C++. After compile and linking, the executable file has the section like .text, .data and etc.

Are there practical ways to change these names to other names? In the advanced option of the linker in Visual Studio properties, with help of merging section, I could change one name of these sections. How can I change all of them? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `#pragma code_seg(".new_name")` , or `bss_seg`, `const_seg`, `data_seg` and `init_seg` for the other types of segments.